# Emacs word-level buffer merge from lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp, diff

I'm aware of how to do a word-level buffer merge with Ediff, however I need to perform a buffer merge from an internal lisp function, without invoking the Ediff control buffers.

I have two buffers, `buf-A` contains:

```
foo bar
```

and `buf-B` contains:

```
foo baz
```

It is given that `buf-B` is always newer than `buf-A` and therefore always preferred. I'd like to produce the following merged `buf-C` buffer:

```
foo <del>bar</del><mark>baz</mark>
```

The template is easy enough, as is setting `ediff-word-mode t`, however, I can't figure out how to call this as an internal function, and passing the preferred diff buffer as arguments.

Revised for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

What about <kbd>M-x ediff-regions-wordwise RET</kbd> ?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Yes and no. I need to call a non-interactive function from lisp. I do want to use Ediff with `ediff-word-mode t` but I can't figure out how to bypass Ediff's interactive UI and just produce the merge buffer.